# Novice question regarding scam token contracts and exchange direct approach

Tags: ether, arbitrum

Im really new regarding the contracts and I found one really fresh that´s a scam and I wanted to study it a little, I´ve been checking that this contract has buy/sells, but it doesnt let people to swap in exchange,so I was thinking, is it possible to try to find a exploit to swap directly from the LP contract?

https://arbiscan.io/address/0xb85c6fbf780eb913dc34aa0b6f74d1e6a15c356f (the scam token)

Comment: Without the source code it isn't worth the effort.